# Troubles with firewall symfony 6. Error: Class "" used for service "security.listener.user_checker.integration" cannot be found

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to update symfony from 3.4 to 6.0.1

And i got an error

```
Class "" used for service "security.listener.user_checker.integration" cannot be found.
```

I have this error for each blocks in firewalls section

```
        integration:
            pattern: ^/integration
            host: %base_host%
            stateless: true
            custom_authenticators:
                - integration.authenticator.token
            provider: integration_provider
```

I checked https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php#L119

and

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L472

So ChildDefinition has no class(but has parent)

And I can't understand how it should work. Which class should be returned in RegisterListenersPass and where it should be set

Comment: from 3.4 to 6 is not convenient (better to refactor froma fresh 6 LTS version), but if you really want to risk to waste much time just read [UPGRADE FROM 3.x to 4.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-4.0.md#upgrade-from-3x-to-40). Each version have its Upgrade DOCS.

Comment: Just to second what @gp_sflover said, there are lots of security changes between 3.4 and 6.x.  Quite a bit was changed in 5.x.  So at a minimum consider making a fresh 6.x project and just try to get your firewalls working.  May as well use the current 6.1 version (with PHP 8.1) while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution.
It does not resolve the base problem, and I still want to figure out with my problem.

But now I can describe service like

```
security.listener.user_checker.integration:
    class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EventListener\UserCheckerListener
```

And the error gone.